# IHow to develop these constrains and conditions in cplex?

Tags: cplex

I had many days to develop the latest two decision variables constrains for each of  beam_reuse[]
and beam_pol[], I need help for developing their constrains in subject to or in an after execute.

```
     int Nbeams=21;
     range beams=x..Nbeams;

     int Nchannels=16;
     range channels=1.. Nchannels;    
      
     int Npol=2;                        // may be 3 or 4 or .....
     range pol= 0..Npol-1;
     int polarization [i in pol]=i;

     int Nreuse=2;                     // may be 1 or 3 or 4 or .....
     range reusee= 1..Nreuse;  
     int reuse [i in reusee]=i;
      
     int Nrows= Npol*Nreuse;
     range rows=1..Nrows;
    
     int TotChannels = Nchannels *Npol*Nreuse;
     
     dvar int first_beam_in_each_row[rows]         in (1..Nbeams);
     dvar int No_beams_in_each_row[rows]         in (0..Nbeams);
     dvar int beam_firstchannel[beams]           in   (channels);
     dvar int beam_nomusedchannel[beams]         in   (channels);
     

     dvar int beam_reuse[beams]                  in    (reuse);
     dvar int beam_pol[beams]                    in    (pol);
   
   
//and my code has the following output:

//Nrows=4;
//Nbeams=21;
//first_beam_in_each_row=[1,7,13,19];
//No_beams_in_each_row=[6,6,6,3];
//beam_firstchannel=[1,3,5,7,9,11,1,3,5,7,9,11,1,3,5,7,9,11,1,6,11];
//beam_nomusedchannel=[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5];
```

Remaining for me:
(1) beam_reuse[beams]
(2) beam_pol[beams]

I want to write these constrains for:
(1) beam_reuse:
i have 2 reuses so will distribute the beams in the 4 rows on these two reuses the beams in the first two rows (first 12 beams) will take reuse[1] =1,  and the beams in the last two rows ( last 9 beams) will take reuse[2]=2.

why 2? because we have two polarization in each reuse, for example if we have 3 polarization then the beams in the first three rows will take reuse[1], and the beams in the other 3 rows will take reuse[2].

(2) beam_pol: i have two polarization for each reuse, so the beams in the first row ( first 6 beams) will take pol[0]=0 and the beams in the second row (second 6 beams) will take pol[1]=1, and the beams in the third next [6 beams] will again take pol[0]=1 but here we have changed the reuse in the above to be 2 not 1 and the beams in the last row (last 3 beams) will take pol[1]=1 again.

Comment: @Alexfleischer need your help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use logical constraints:

```
 int Nbeams=21;
 int x=1;
 range beams=x..Nbeams;

 int Nchannels=16;
 range channels=1.. Nchannels;    
  
 int Npol=2;                        // may be 3 or 4 or .....
 range pol= 0..Npol-1;
 int polarization [i in pol]=i;

 int Nreuse=2;                     // may be 1 or 3 or 4 or .....
 range reusee= 1..Nreuse;  
 int reuse [i in reusee]=i;
  
 int Nrows= Npol*Nreuse;
 range rows=1..Nrows;

 int TotChannels = Nchannels *Npol*Nreuse;
 
 dvar int first_beam_in_each_row[rows]         in (1..Nbeams);
 dvar int No_beams_in_each_row[rows]         in (0..Nbeams);
 dvar int beam_firstchannel[beams]           in   (channels);
 dvar int beam_nomusedchannel[beams]         in   (channels);
 

 dvar int beam_reuse[beams]             in    (reusee);
 dvar int beam_pol[beams]                   in    (pol);
 
 subject to
 {
   forall(i in beams) (i<=first_beam_in_each_row[3]-1) => (beam_reuse[i]==1);
   forall(i in beams) (i>=first_beam_in_each_row[3]) => (beam_reuse[i]==2);
   
   
   forall(r in rows:r!=1)
     forall(i in beams) ((i>=first_beam_in_each_row[r-1]) && (i<=first_beam_in_each_row[r]-1)) => (beam_pol[i]==1-r mod 2);
   
 }
```

works fine